# After converting image to bitmap, image is black or it doesn't displayed at all

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap, mat, bitmapfactory

When I'm trying to convert the Mat image to Bitmap the image doesn't displayed in my device, on the contrary when I use Bitmap.Config.RGB_565 the displayed image is black. Here is my code:

```
 Mat src = new Mat(bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
 imgToProcess = Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, src);
 Bitmap bmpOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgToProcess.cols(),imgToProcess.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
 Utils.matToBitmap(imgToProcess, bmpOut);
 imv.setImageBitmap(bmpOut);
 rotateImage(bmpOut);
```

and I'm using all the following libraries:

```
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
```

I have already try to convert my image to different colorspace before converting to bitmap with `Imgproc.cvtColor()` but the app was stopped working.
How can i fix my code so i can begin with the image processing? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `imgToProcess = Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, src);`. Please explain this statement. If the bitmap is converted to a Mat. Then imgToProcess will contain the Mat afterwards? You defined imgToProcess as Mat? Why dont you show?. If so then for what the src parameter is needed?

Comment: Yes, i already have difined the imgToProcess as a Mat and it will contain the Mat.

Comment: my problem is with matToBitmap convertion.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation isn't *overly* clear, but it appears that `ARGB_8888` actually means: 8-bits per channel with a channel order of Alpha, Red, Green, Blue.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html

When you use `RGB_565` (as the link above explains a bit more clearly), you are getting channels in the order of "Red, Green, Blue", no alpha channel.

Bitmap images do not support Alpha channels -- a channel that defines opaqueness (the opposite of transparency), where a value 1.0 (or all `1`s in binary) is fully opaque (not at all transparent) and a value of 0.0 is fully transparent (totally see-through).

You are not seeing anything in your conversion because you are trying to write 4-channel image into the 3-channel support of a bitmap, essentially mapping "Alpha, Red, Green" (ARG) into the "Red, Green, Blue" of the bitmap image expectations.

Now, technically, you could do wacky things to make ARG appear as an image in an RGB format, but that also assumes that A and RGB are all in the same domain (`0-to-255` or `0.0-to-1.0`). And that would be mostly unreadable to anyone trying to follow your code.

Most likely you're also getting a black image when you do use the proper `RGB_565` format because you did a `new Mat(...)` and have not assigned it any contents, and by design the `Mat` class likely instantiates its objects with channels filled with `0`, and `(0,0,0)` in `(R,G,B)` format is a black pixel, so every pixel is black.

Your solution is to switch to the proper `RGB_565` if you want a bitmap -- and only use `ARGB_8888` on images that support alpha-masks (also called alpha channels), like PNGs (Portable Network Graphics [Images]) -- and then also be sure to fill in your pixels with the contents that you want for color values.

Your code is correct if you use `RGB_565`, but it is also *correctly* giving you an all-black image because you haven't modified any of the pixel contents yet.